# What Inertial effects should be considered to achieve blade stability on a Variable Pitch Propeller tailoredby aerodynamic loads?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, propeller, stability, constant-speed-propeller

I am developing a self adjusting variable pitch propeller tailored by its pitching moments due to aerodynamic loads setting the blade rotation axis in an offset from the aerodynamic center as shown below.

[image]

At the moment i am trying to attain static and dynamic stability of the blade due to mass/Inertial effects. I have created a sketch as shown on the following figure, based on my so far understanding on inertial effects which represents a blade airfoil section and the centrifugal force (OR NOT??) acting on a mass particle.

[image]

Mass: ρ*dx*dy*dr

Offset from Pitch Axis x

Offset from longitudinal Axis y

Force: (ρ*dx*dy*dr)*rω^2

Component along the x-axis: (x/r)*Force

Pitch Moment: y*(x/r)*Force

And now comes the difficult part. I suppose that here i need to consider the theory of three dimensional kinetics of a rigid body and angular momentum, however i am confused on defining the coordinate systems on the blade as well as which exact moments and products of Inertia have to take into account. If i am not wrong, here a fixed coordinate reference system and one that rotates with the twisting of the blade have to be defined.  The question is where the coordinate reference system has to be defined; on the blade axis of rotation, C.G, or somewhere else?

Finally i have informed that  to compute the blade's dynamic stability, i will need also to consider blade flapping (i.e., motion of the blade out of plane with the rotation of the propeller), and pitching (or twisting) and this is another part i am struggling too!

Comment: @mins Actually i have managed to compute twist and chord distributions but i suppose that this is not an issue for the current situation (It is just a sum up on the overall pitch angle (twist) and a variation on the coordinates(chord length)). This is a propeller for small UAVs but i assume theory is similar with heli's tail rotor yes!